# GNU make how to make targets in different directory

Tags: makefile, directory, target

I would like make to produce targets in different directory than where the Makefile resides. It concerns the output of M4 macro processing step using *.in files.
I can't get the pattern rule right; I presume the target definition is not right, but how to specify? The project structure is below

```
                prj
                 +
                 |
        -+-------+-----------+---------------+
         |                   |               |
        inc                 src            config
         |                   |               |
        a1-1.h           +----------+--     conf.m4 
        a1-2.h           |
                        app
                         |
                         a1-1.in
                         a1-2.in
                         Makefile
```

The Makefile code:

```
M4INSRCS=$(wildcard *.in)
HTARGETS=$(M4INSRCS:.in=.h)
HDIR=../../inc

.PHONY : all
all: $(HTARGETS) $(MINSRCS)
    @echo "INSRCS $(M4INSRCS)"
    @echo "HTARGETS $(HTARGETS)"
    @echo "HDIR $(HDIR)"

$(HDIR)/%.h : %.in
    cp $< $(HDIR)/$@
    touch $(HDIR)/$@
```

Make reports:
make: *** No rule to make target `a1-1.h', needed by` all'.  Stop.

Comment: Well, `all` depends on `a1-1.h` but you haven't defined a rule to build that target.  So make tells you that there's no rule to build it.

Comment: well actually the target is ../../inc/a1-1.h; I thinkI try with text procesing in Makefile to build for each target a mk include

Comment: You have set `HTARGETS` to the value `a1-1.h a1-2.h` (fixing the typo in your example).  Then you list `all: $(HTARGETS)`.  So the `all` target depends on the prerequisites `a1-1.h` and `a1-2.h` and those are the files that make will try to build.  You have not told make how to build those targets, so make gives an error.  If you want make to build something different than `a1-1.h` and `a1-2.h`, then you have to change the prerequisites you asked it to build.

Answer (score 0):

I thougt there was a link between the 'all' target prequisite HTARGETS and the $(HDIR)/%.h rule. Apparently not. So I completed the HTARGET elements(file names) with the HDIR prefix. And now I get the desired result

```
M4INSRCS=$(wildcard *.in)   # the set of input file names
HFILES=$(M4INSRCS:.in=.h)   # the set of target file names
HDIR=../../inc              # the place to store the target files
CONF_DIR=../../config
CONF_FNAM=conf.m4
CONFIG=$(CONF_DIR)/$(CONF_FNAM)

# get HTARGETS to be of the format dir/dir/target-file-name
HTARGETS=$(foreach FILE,$(HFILES),$(HDIR)/$(FILE))
#HTARGETS now have format ../../inc/a1-1.h ../../inc/a1-2.h . . . .

# output depends on actual state of targets, *.in files and a config file
all: $(HTARGETS) $(M4INSRCS) $(CONFIG)

# here we have the pattern for a HTARGETS element
$(HDIR)/%.h: %.in $(CONFIG)
    cp $< $@
    touch $@
```